# Login with Facebook with my IBM Worklight web application

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, ibm-mobilefirst

I created a simple web application using IBM Worklight.
Now, I am trying to use Facebook api using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/#samples tutorial Where
a user can login with their Facebook id.

In order to set up this functionality, I need to give the siteUri of my web app so i added web environment to my app and got app URI as
http://[Ip Address]:8080/apps/services/www/zShop/mobilewebapp/

But, when I run the application, I get this error

API Error Code: 191 API Error Description:
The specified URL is not owned by the application Error Message:
Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Not sure what is wrong, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to host your app on a human-readable domain (eg. example.com) instead of one reached by a literal IP address.  If you don't have a domain, you could try adding an entry in your laptop/desktop's `hosts` file so you don't have to use the IP address (I haven't tried this with FB apps).

You can also get free webhosting from Heroku. It's free because it's starter-package level hosting.  There's a good Heroku tutorial here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

So ensure you can load the app in a browser using a domain name (eg. example.com).

Then make sure your app settings has this domain name configured:

[App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) > Basic > App Domain

Then enter your domain as written in "Step 1" of that tutorial.