# IBM Worklight - config app facebook to run in real device

Tags: android, facebook, ibm-mobilefirst, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have a Worklight-based app that uses Facebook Login. When I preview it everything is ok  (I can click the login button and the Facebook Login dialog box is displayed), but when I  run it on the Android Emulator or device I get the following error in LogCat:

```
05-28 09:17:35.391: I / Web Console (751): URL has not been configured
> to allow application.: One or more of the provided URL is not set app
> permissions. URL must match the URL of the web page or the page URL or
> domain is a subdomain of the domain of application. at
> https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=321009794697186&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&domain=&origin=2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D24%23cb%3Df1eae8b44c%26origin%3Dfile%253A%252F%252F%252Ff3688c0c94%26domain%3D%26relation%3Dparent&sdk=joey:1
```

This is my Facebook configuration in the app:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {   FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxx', // App ID   //  channelUrl : 'http://stormy-sands-2143.herokuapp.com/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
    oauth: true   });


  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously    (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);    }(document));
```

This is my Facebook configuration in the facebook.com app:
[image]

What do I need to configure for this to run in a device?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079285/login-with-facebook-with-my-ibm-worklight-web-application

Comment: I've tried this,but it's not work.Have any way ?

Comment: Why is the beginning of your function commented out? // Load the SDK asynchronously    (function(d){

Comment: I don't think it will work if you're pointing to localhost...

Comment: So, how to config it to work, please tell me ?

Comment: Point to your SERVER instead of LOCALHOST?

Comment: Point to SERVER like heroku server,please see my updated question,Have i config my . host in system32/drivers/etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this error happens to you because you are using the Facebook JavaScript SDK.
This SDK is meant for when the web resources are on a server:

- web sites or
- mobile web apps

The Facebook App requires an App Domain/Site URL that a site or mobile web app would have, but an Android app doesn't have a domain...

A Worklight Hybrid app with the Android environment, while using web resources, is **not** a "**mobile web** app", it's **an app**.

Thus, you should either use a [Cordova plug-in](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=cordova%20facebook%20login) that implements Facebook login across platforms (whichever is available by the plug-in), or use the [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/).

Comment: My app build on worklight using loginfb to get user infomation and using it for my app,but if i using fb sdk for android to login and get user infomation ,How i can used information i've get from that to my app  ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please familiarize yourself with the Facebook Login SDK for Android, it contains all the API methods you require.

Comment: please view this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637355/combine-android-with-worklight) i've explain my question in that.

Comment: Ok. For this current question, please mark it as Answered if it has been answered for you. Thanks.

Comment: @IdanAdar as I see existing Cordova plugins for Facebook sharing purposes are only available for iOS and Android, What about BlackBerry and Windows Phone ? Which solution do you suggest to implement FaceBook + Twitter sharing in the 4 plateforms?