# IBM Worklight - Combine Facebook SDK Java code in Worklight application

Tags: android, facebook, ibm-mobilefirst, facebook-sdk-3.0

I can use the Facebook SDK for Android to login with Facebook and get user information. When doing this all of the code is in `src/com.name/MainActivity.java`.

But when using Worklight, everything I code is in Worklight now, in `assest/www/default` and nothing in MainActivity.java.

My question is, if I've used the Facebook SDK in MainActivity.java how can I use that in the Worklight app?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First please familiarize yourself with [creating Cordova plug-ins in Worklight](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova) (specifically, [this training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/06_05_Android_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf) and [sample app](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/WindowsPhone8CordovaPluginProject.zip)).

That's how you should integrate your native code in a Worklight app, by using a Cordova plug-in.

Otherwise, there is also an [official plug-in by Facebook for Cordova](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) (which should be integrated in the same way as you learn in the training module).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion:) i've tried only few POC's in worklight never tried third party libraries +1